# kotlin inheritance conversion results in unused property

Tags: kotlin

I have 2 classes I want to refactor to use inheritance, where class1:class2

class1 forwards the shared value to class2

before:

```
data class1(val uniq1: Long, val uniq2:Long, val uniq3:Long, val shared:Long): Parcelable
data class2(val shared:Long):Parcelable
```

after:

```
open class2(open val shared:Long): Parcelable
class1(val uniq1: Long, val uniq2:Long, val uniq3:Long, override val shared:Long):class2(shared), Parcelable
```

invocation:

```
val class1obj = class1(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)
```

kotlin warns that uniq2 is unused-why?

Comment: You never read that value. Just proceed with your project and it should disappear in time.

Comment: I am using uniq2 by passing in 2L.  It does not complain about the other arguments(1L, 3L, 4L)

Comment: Passing it as argument is only a value write, lint is looking for value reads. Try adding `class1obj.uniq2` below your invocation and see if warning disappears.

Comment: Why do you declare shared as a val in class1? You don't need to - class1 isn't a data class. Just declare it as a constructor parameter